# How to save different numpy arrays with np.savetxt?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I would like to save different numpy arrays with np.savetxt('xx.csv'). The np.arrays are (m,n) and I would like to add before the first column a list of index and above each line a list of header. Both lists consist of strings.

When I do multiple savetxt it erased the previous values.

I considered creating a huge matrix by merging every numpy arrays but doubt about the optimality.

Thanks for your help

Comment: I would like to have a blank line between each arrays

Comment: You need to open the file in append mode, and pass the opened file to the `savetxt` function.  Write any spacer lines directly.  If you give `savetxt` a filename, it creates a new file in `write` mode, effectively deleting anything you wrote to that name before.

Comment: Nice, that works. thanks!